# What is limit and offset in prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I wanted to select huge amount of data from database and also want to edit the data without affecting the original data from database. How to do this by using prepared statement? And can you explain what is limit and offset in preparedstatement in Java?

Comment: Editing without affecting the database? So just temporary? Or will you make a 2nd database, or add the modified values? It's unclear. Not so good is, to intermix multiple, loose related questions. If you get 3 answers for your 3 questions - which will you accept?

Answer (score 0):

The `PreparedStatement` is just going to help you create a query on the database.  Once you run the query to select the data you have to pull it out of the `ResultSet` and typically hand it off to other objects to modify (like GUI classes, etc.)

If you want to make changes you will have to run another query to Update or Insert changes.  (Note in some cases you can use the `ResultSet` to edit data, but this doesn't sound like what you are after).